# Apache Stuck at Active: reloading (reload) while performing rsyslog on Amazon linux 2

Tags: php, apache, segmentation-fault

We have recently updated the apache to 2.4.58 and php to 8.2.9 on our test server.
From then the apache is stuck at reloading while performing rsyslog.

In the Logs under /var/log/messages, found the below error.

httpd[26166]: segfault at 7f5b9d604080 ip 00007f5b9e6052d9 sp 00007ffc428a1400 error 4 in libphp.so[7f5b9e2cd000+4f4000]

The Apache status shows Active: reloading (reload) and the Site goes down

We have to restart Apache to bring the Site up. The rsyslog is a cron job and runs every day to rotate the log files. As soon as this job runs, the Apache stucks at reloading and Site goes down

The OS is Amazon linux 2

I am just a beginner in php and no idea how to proceed